# All my .htaccess redirects are going to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect all my website traffic from any url to https://, secure ssl using a .htaccess file. This has to match the current domain and redirect including any sub url's.

My code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop.test.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The issue i am having is that all traffic is being sent to index.php

shop.test.com/testurl

goes to - https://shop.test.com/index.php

expected - https://shop.test.com/testurl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to another rule that writes everything to `index.php` and uses that as front controller.

**Make sure you place above rule as your very first rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.**

Comment: is that likely to be the only issue with the code that i already have, the reason being is that i can only test this on a live environment

Comment: Yes if you move it up as the first rule you won't find this problem happening anymore. But do you see this rule below other rules in live system?

Comment: Ah i see now my mistake, after moving the apache code to the top of my htaccess file the rules worked. Thanks.